# Magento 2 Project How to setup in git via local

Tags: magento2.3, git, data-push

i have magento 2 project and i want to setup in local via **git**

and after setup how to run git command like `commit` , `push` or else

any tutorial or video available for that ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're beginner, I'd recommend start from [githubFlow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), then [helloworld](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) and finally a nice [mediumBlog](https://medium.com/swlh/a-beginners-guide-to-github-e4747a93765c) for git commands.

Comment: thanks for your answer you have any reference or link

Comment: Links are given, just click on them.

Answer (score 0):

Following files are added in our project repos:

Composer.json

Composer.lock

App/Code

App/Design

App/etc/Config.php

Readme

Gitignore

There are approaches to even add the vendor folder, but this is preference.

Comment: thanks for your answer any video or tutorial available ?